# Source for North American public boat and kayak launch sites?

Tags: data, north-america

Does anyone know of a good source for North American public boat and kayak launch sites for mapping in a GIS. I would prefer a web service.

Comment: Worldwide? Or for a specific country?

Comment: Sorry, I should have put that in. North America only..

Comment: Did you do it by state? Would you consider sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a National Dataset with this information in it.  There are several regional web pages that have this information for the state/county level.  Is there a specific state you are interested in?

For Example:

See this topic as it seems to be exactly what you are looking for:  http://freegeographytools.com/2009/marine-navigation-gis-data

Great Lakes Boat Launches - http://www.great-lakes.net/gis/metadata/acp/

Boat Launch Ramps in Many States - http://www.launchingramps.com/

State Files:

LA - https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/louisiana-marinas-and-boat-launches-geographic-nad83-losco-2004-marinas-losco-2004

NY - https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/boat-launch-sites-by-waterbody

CA - http://www.dbw.ca.gov/maps/facilityindex.asp?searchfield=FACILITY_TYPE&searchterm=Launch

MA - http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/ofba.html

WI - http://dnr.wi.gov/topic/lands/boataccess/

MD - http://dnr2.maryland.gov/Boating/Pages/water-access/boatramps.aspx

PA - http://fishandboat.com/access.htm - fill out the form to send to Commission office for this information

CT - http://www.depdata.ct.gov/maps/boating/boatingmap.htm

CO - https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6b17044b2d2a4ef69b7b30c503bf8828

WA - http://wdfw.wa.gov/lands/water_access/

And finally a third party proprietary application that holds this data:

https://activecaptain.com/

Comment: Thx, that's great. Yeah I was coming to the to the same conclusion that there is no central source but will do state by state. Thx!

Comment: Did you do it by state? Would you consider sharing?